# Photoshop: continuous selection to different layer automatically

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, selections

Let's say I have a picture: black lines on a white background. I can select all the white parts with color selection. What I need is to have every continous selection moved to a separate layer. Can I do this automatically is Photoshop?
In this example above, I want to have 7 different layers with the seven "tile" without having to select all of them one by one and create a new layer from it.

[image]

Comment: I would've probably drawn these shapes with pentool.

Comment: I think you'll have to do it one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this question is ancient, but this might be useful nevertheless if someone comes here to look for a solution. This isn't "automatic" - but not exactly complicated. A few mouse clicks and you'll have the job done.

1. Use the Magic Wand Tool, set to "Contiguous" in the tool options.
2. Make a selection, then copy and paste. The result is a new layer.
3. Select the original layer again.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until complete.

Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Ctrl+J is one less operation than Ctrl+C and then Ctrl+V...

Answer (score 0):

select each part of white tiles with magic tool or quick section tool then ctrl + j

Answer (score 0):

On the particular artwork shown, select the black lines with the Magic Wand tool, then invert the selection. The inverted selection will be each of the 7 white areas. You can create a new layer and use the selection as you wish.